# Paypal payouts tracking

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I use paypal REST api (sanbdbox). I need to make automatic payouts, track it, get the list of all payments (including created payout via REST api). I managed creating single batch payout and get status for it. But I can't get list of all payments (income and outcome) and match my payouts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Sure, I googled and researched this problem before, but didn't find anything helpful. Seems, Paypal NVP api isn't compatible with REST api. I use REST for create single payout and check it status, but I need ability to get list of all payouts and match it with my internal list of payouts.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a payout store the sender_batch_id you use, and when you get a response store the payout_batch_id / payout_item_id then update poll the status using

> /v1/payments/payouts/payout_batch_id

or

> /v1/payments/payouts-item/payout_item_id

Preferably instead use the [webhooks API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/) to get a notification when the status changes, then update the status accordingly.

Either of these approaches requires you to somehow keep track of your own payouts. I do not see a way to list previously submitted payouts in the REST API. There are of course many ways you could organize and track your requests.